# Calculate Sum change from last 20 records

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I'm sorry for bad type English.
I have a Table name's **Volumes**.

My Solution show u in Image (because i can't speak English and good explain):

[image]

And this is my Query Myql php:

```
SELECT buyVolume, volume,symbol,(SELECT SUM(buyVolume) 
  FROM wp_volume v2 WHERE v2.id >= v1.id AND symbol ='".$symbol."') as 
   sumVolumes 
     FROM wp_volume v1
WHERE time >= '$time' AND symbol ='".$symbol."' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Symbol, percent change and date seem largely irrelevant to this problem. I suggest you omit these columns from the problem, and instead see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: With respect, please get help from an English speaker to [edit] your question.

Comment: Just put and additional condition in the `where` part of your subquery to calculate `sumvolumes`: `AND v2.id <= 20`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I don't think you've thought this through

Comment: @Strawberry just going by whatever little I could figure out from OP's problem definition

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya The post mentions 'last 20 records'. The idea that the last 20 records might consistently be numbered 1 through 20 is frankly implausible.